# GAE: Controlling max idle instances

Tags: google-app-engine

I know that there was some functionality for controlling the max idle instances and max latency after which a new instance was started. Now I can't find those in the new console.

Is this completely gone, or has the mechanism changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those settings have all moved into your application's configuration files. Here are the python docs on it https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/modules/#Python_Instance_scaling_and_class